# Magento - Incorrect Category title

Tags: magento

On the Magento admin Panel my category title for example is: Outdoor Furniture. Then on the website the category title is correct, but when you click on that category the title at the top of the page is incorrect. i.e. Outdoor Furniture blah blah blah. How do I get rid of the blah blah blah?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get help with your problem please see how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update category name under "**Page Title**" also :[image]

Comment: I have done this but still a mysterious addition there that i cannot find anywhere.

Comment: @SamG  try clear cache from backend, also from  var/cache, check site in private window , also if do reindex once......

Comment: have cleaned all caches and still no change

Comment: @SamG what about other catgories , can you check by changing the theme for that category .....

Comment: Its the same problem for all categories and sub categories. The exact same text is added to each one. Pages are not an issue they are all easy to edit. Its just the categories

Comment: @SamG check this once : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73212/default-meta-titles-for-category-pages

Comment: @SamG did you found solution ? if so feel free to accept an answer......